# Query for field existence in CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Suppose I have an optional field called 'xyz' in the list of documents I've indexed in CloudSearch.

How do I query CloudSearch so that it returns only those documents that contain 'xyz'?

If I know up front, that it's a positive integer, I can probably do something like this to get the required list:
`q=xyz:[0,}&q.parser=structured`

But how do I do it if 'xyz' stores some other type like a string or a list of ints/strings etc.,?

BTW, I've used Solr before, and there, I could simply do `q=xyz:*` to achieve this. Does CloudSearch support such regular expressions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591773/amazon-cloudsearch-filter-if-exists

Answer (score 1):

You can query for non empty values in a field using * operator, in your case its going to be xyz:* This will only work if you are using Lucene parser for your query to CloudSearch.

Comment: Query Parser is attribute as "queryParser" in search api, example code:

$result = $this->client->search(array(
   'query' => $str,
   //'queryParser' => 'simple|structured|lucene|dismax',
   'queryParser' => 'lucene',
   'size' => 100,
   'return' => '_score,_all_fields'
   ));