# Amazon Cloudsearch : Filter if exists

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-cloudsearch

I have an amazon cloudsearch domain. The aim is to filter if the field 'language' exists.
Not all objects have a language, and I want to have the ones which do have a language filtered, but the ones that do not have any language to also be returned.

I want to filter with
`( or language:'en' language:null )`

However, null cannot be passed within a string.

Is this possible? If so how would it be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked elsewhere aswell, it seems :

The simplest way to do that, is to set a default value for the field, and then use that value for your null.

For example, set the default to the string "null", then you can easily test for that.

I believe you can add a default value, and re-index, and that should reapply the default.

Comment: I strongly recommend not doing this. Using magic values like this is always a bad idea. This should not be the accepted answer. The correct answer to detect a null is to use `(not (prefix language=''))`

Comment: Just to correct @justin.m.chase comment if you don't see his answer below, should be `(not (prefix field='language' ''))`

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to use the Lucene query parser you can express your query like this:

`(*:* OR -language:*) OR language:en`

Note: The funky `(*:* OR ...)` construct is necessary because of the way Lucene treats negated OR clauses.

In general, you can filter by existence / non-existence of a field with the Lucene query parser:

All documents containing `field`: `field:[* TO *]`

All documents not containing `field`: `-field:[* TO *]`

Note: If `field` is textual (text or literal datatypes) you don't need range queries and you can shorten the above to:

`field:*` and `-field:*`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to cleanly do exactly what you want, but here are two options:

1. Index a new field called something like `has_language`, setting its value to `language!=null` at doc submission time.
2. This is more of a hack because range should only be used with integers, but I have used it successfully on literal fields `(range field=language [0,})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for existence by using the `prefix` or `range` operators depending on your field type. If the type is a term or a string then you can use prefix like so:

```
(prefix field=example '')
```

This will yield only results that are not null for the field `example`.

For dates you can use an inclusive date range:

```
(range field=updated ['0000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',})
```

This will only include items with an `updated` date after the given time, items with a null updated date will not be included. You can do other similar searches for other field types.

Similarly you can use the `not` operator to get the set of items with null fields.

For example, All items with a null `example` field:

```
(not (prefix field=example ''))
```