# CloudSearch, How to find documents where a key is not defined?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudsearch

Rather simple question here. Using CloudSearch, how do I find an object that does *NOT* have a certain key/property defined.

eg. I have been storing Car objects all along without indexing their price. Now I have began indexing Car objects with their msrp... how do I find the Car objects stored without any indexed price?

(and price:null)
(and price:undefined)
and other similar 'falsy' statements and their stringified permutations all do not work.

I am using AWS sdk in Node.js.

TIA!

Niko

Answer (score 0):

The option that will work without any reindexing is a range search like

`(NOT (range field=price [0,}))`

which matches cars with a price that is not between 0 and infinity (eg ones with no price). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837887/cloudsearch-return-results-when-a-field-does-not-exist/28868511#28868511) for a discussion of other options.

Side note: I get the impression that you may be using CloudSearch to store your data. If so, I would consider using a datastore (which are designed to store data) rather than CloudSearch (which is a search engine). For one, it'll make this sort of query much easier.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion! just fyi, I am not using cloudsearch as a datastore. it just also holds the query-able fields of our data.

Comment: Ok cool, that means you can consider some of the other options. I think setting things without a price to some sentinel value like -1 might be worth considering.

Comment: well yes and no... the cars without a price dont have a price because we did not care about price before (in reality, cars always have prices unfortunately :( )

Comment: Sure but you can easily test for that in whatever language you're using (node.js)?